# Transferring SSL certificate to new server

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, godaddy

We're swicthing from an OSCommerce website to Magento and are also swicthing servers.  The old server is on Apache and our new one is on NGINX. The SSL certificate we have seems to have been purchased from GODADDY.

I've almost figured out how to switch our SSL certifcate from our old server to our new server.  But have a few questions?

**1. REKEY CERTIFICATE**

I've discovered three types of SSL files from the old OSCommerce site apache virtual host:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/11-2013/09********ss.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/11-2013/server.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/11-2013/gd_bundle.crt
```

Can I just copy these to a location on the new server and reference them in the NGINX configuration file?  Or do I need to generate a new ssl key, [re-key](https://www.godaddy.com/help/rekey-certificate-4976) the crt file(which one)?

**2. NGINX CONFIGURATION**
The NGINX configuration only seems to need reference to two files Apache does?

```
# Specify path to your SSL certificates.
#ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/yourcertificate.crt;
#ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/yourcertificate.key;
```

Which CRT file should I reference for NGINX, what about the other one?

**3. SSL 3.0 & SHA1**
When I check our site on [DigiCert's SSL checker](https://www.digicert.com/help/) it says:

> Protocol Support
>
> TLS 1.0, SSL 3.0
>
> SSL 3.0 is an outdated protocol version with known vulnerabilities.
>
> SSL certificate
>
> Common Name = ourdomain.com
>
> Subject Alternative Names = ourdomain.com, www.ourdomain.com
>
> Issuer = Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority
>
> Serial Number = *****************
>
> SHA1 Thumbprint = ***************************
>
> Key Length = 4096 bit
>
> Signature algorithm = SHA1 + RSA (deprecated)
>
> Secure Renegotiation: Supported

How do I ensure we are using the correct protocol & SHA?  Is this something I change in the new nginx configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

`ssl_certificate_key` should contain what's presently in server.key, ie they 
server's unencrypted private key.

`ssl_certificate` should contain the server's certificate and the certificate chain, [as explained in the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html), **in that order**. So, that's basically the output of `cat 09********ss.crt gd_bundle.crt`

A handy online tool to quickly check out what exactly each of these `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` / `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` blocks contain is https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html - if you have a machine with openssl installed available, you can of course use

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout
```

With respect to the SSL/TLS configuration, I like this [page in the Mozilla wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS). It explains most of the acronyms that you may encounter, and gives sound advice relative to sensible configurations. There's an accompanying online tool that will create reference setups for Apache, nginx, haproxy and the AWS LB, [here](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/). As an example, a full nginx config, featuring OCSP stapling and HSTS using the intermediate profile looks like this, **but you need to understand that these profiles evolve** and should thus be updated regularly.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    # certs sent to the client in SERVER HELLO are concatenated in ssl_certificate
    ssl_certificate /path/to/signed_cert_plus_intermediates;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/private_key;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
    ssl_dhparam /path/to/dhparam.pem;

    # intermediate configuration. tweak to your needs.
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    # OCSP Stapling ---
    # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    ## verify chain of trust of OCSP response using Root CA and Intermediate certs
    ssl_trusted_certificate /path/to/root_CA_cert_plus_intermediates;

    resolver <IP DNS resolver>;

    ....
}
```

Once all that put in place and tested, head over to [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) and run a test. If you missed something, you'll see what still needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

1. First part:

   ```
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/11-2013/09********ss.crt
   ```

This is the public certificate for your website. This is the one you would **rekey to change the SHA1 to SHA2**.

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/11-2013/server.key
```

This is private certificate for your web server.

```
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/11-2013/gd_bundle.crt
```

This is the intermediate certificates bundle to roll up your web server certificate to the root authority at godaddy (because their root certificate is not necessarily trusted by browsers by default)

2. This gives instructions on how to configure NGINX to use a intermediate certificate chain (which you will most likely need to do since you needed to do so on your Apache server): [nginx docs: Configuring HTTPS servers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)
3. You would not change the certificate configuration in the NGINX configuration file.  Once a certificate has capabilities you can turn those capabilities off and on in the config file (per the answer from fvu) but first you need to basically "upgrade" your certificate itself.  GoDaddy has a couple of articles that may be helpful for this, the first just describes what you are doing when you make this change:  https://www.godaddy.com/help/rekey-certificate-4976  the second tells you how to actually do it using their service:  https://www.godaddy.com/help/rekey-certificate-4976.

After you have all that in place, then you can use ssllabs to test, but that will only work if your new site is up and running on the right hostname in DNS (which you may not want to do if you still need the site up on Apache until you are finished).  Assuming you have root somewhere on a linux/unix machine, you can use openssl to test this:

1. Enter your new NGINX service's IP address as the name of the site you want to test against.  So your main site stays where it is on Apache, you only tell your local machine to find it at the NGINX site.  Once you've done that, then run the following command and see what it outputs:

   ```
   openssl s_client -connect hostname:port
   ```

Or use this command, which points you directly to what you are checking:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473076/how-do-i-check-if-my-ssl-certificate-is-sha1-or-sha2-on-the-commandline

Comment: add `-servername hostname` to the openssl statement above to correctly use SNI